# Sorting with Python Flink API

Tags: apache-flink

I'm looking to sort on the results of a `groupBy` but don't see a supported way as there is with Java / Scala. I'm thinking I could materialize the iterator in function passed to a `reduce_group` but that seems clunky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to sort your grouped set by calling

```
    grouped_set.sort_group(0, Order.ASCENDING)
```